# participle to qualify noun and pronoun

Tags: present-participles, supplementation, participial-adjectives

I've heard that participle is used to qualify a noun or pronoun. Here are two sentences:

1. Hearing the noise, the boy woke up.
2. Taking the pen,the boy ran.

source: http://www.englishgrammar.org/participles/

In both of these sentences, participle(hearing and taking)has been used before a noun.

My questions:

1. How does "hearing' and 'taking' qualify the noun?
2. Do they qualify 'noise' and 'pen' because participles are before 'noise'and 'pen'?
3. I don't know how participles can qualify a pronoun, could you provide some examples?

Comment: You can find this meaning of *qualify* in most dictionaries, I believe. Here's one in Macmillan Dictionary: [qualify](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/qualify): 5 [transitive] *linguistics* a word that qualifies another word gives more information about it. For example, in “the dog barked furiously,” the adverb “furiously” qualifies the verb “barked.”

Comment: @Damkerng,Thank you for helping to know it,I looked up it in http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/qualify too and found this meaning too
"to limit the strength or meaning of a statement: I'd like to qualify my criticisms of the school's failings, by adding that it's a very happy place.  [ T ] SPECIALIZED language In grammar, a word or phrase that qualifies another word or phrase limits its meaning and makes it less general: In the sentence "He walked quickly along the road", "quickly" and "along the road" qualify "walked".

Comment: @someone, I don't know what downvote mean, why there's downvote here in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand *qualify* correctly—*modify* is the more usual term—but your "rule" needs some adjustment.

1. *Hearing* and *taking* do not modify the noun *boy*. (I will say more about what they **do** modify at the end.)
2. As present participles, *hearing* and *taking* may act as adjectives, so they **could** modify *boy*. Present participles without following complements are taken to modify a noun if they are set in the ordinary adjective position, between the determiners (if there are any) and the noun. This is quite common with the present participles of intransitive verbs like *run* and *listen*:

   > the running boy  *... ≈ the boy who is (or was) running*
   >   the listening boy  *... ≈ the boy who is (or was) listening. Compare an ordinary adjective,* angry:
   >   the angry boy

   You will occasionally find the present participles of transitive verbs like *hear* and *take* in this adjective position, but it's unusual with the participles of most transitive verbs.<sup>†</sup> These participles are usually the heads of phrases with following direct objects, and any adjective or participle which is followed by an object or complement or modifier must be placed immediately after the nouns in order to qualify it:

   > The boy hearing the noise *... ≈ the boy who hears (or heard) the noise*
   >   The boy taking the pen *... ≈ the boy who takes (or took) the pen —compare*
   >   The boy angry with his parents
3. Ordinarily, adjectives (including participles) **cannot** modify personal pronouns. This is because a noun and its determiners, modifiers and complements form a closed entity, a **noun phrase**—any modifiers have to be placed **inside** that noun phrase. But what a personal pronoun 'stands for' and acts as is not a noun but an entire noun phrase; you can't add any determiners or modifiers, because they would be **outside** the noun phrase:

   > <s>the</s> it
   >   <s>an angry</s> him

How then are we to understand the participle phrases in your sentences?

> **Hearing the noise,** the boy woke up.
>   **Taking the pen,** the boy ran.

There's a clue in the commas here. These aren't just mechanical marks to clarify the structure: they reflect an actual separation in speech, which marks the participle phrases as **supplements**—something outside the main clause and added to it.

These participle phrases are in fact distinct *clauses*. They aren't independent clauses like *the boy woke up* or *the boy ran*, because they don't have finite verbs inflected for tense, person and number. They aren't full clauses, either, because they don't have explicit subjects; we infer that their subjects are the same as the subjects of the clause to which they are subordinated—in both cases, *the boy*. So these clauses don't "modify" *the boy*; rather, *the boy* is the "anchor" which relates them to the main clause.

If these participle clauses may be said to "modify" anything, it is the main clause itself.  Such clauses typically express something which causes the action of the main clause (as in your sentences), or some purpose which the action of the main clause is directed toward, or the manner in which the action of the main clause is performed.

> **Hearing the noise,** the boy woke up.
>   **Hoping to escape,** the boy fled.
>   **Moving stealthily,** the boy snatched the pen.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>When a present participle of a transitive verb is used this way it usually has a somewhat different meaning. Often the participle has 'forked' off from the verb as an independent adjective. *Hearing*, for instance, can be used as an independent adjective: *a hearing boy* is not a boy who hears something but a boy who is **capable** of hearing—a boy who is not deaf.</sub>

Comment: I consider this answer as highly advanced.I understand that you fully tried to answer me.And it's common to have complex words used in an advanced answer of a grammatical question as it's in your answer.Being just a learner,It's more difficult to understand some grammatical words for me too.

Comment: @stoneyB.I'm again asking!!!
1.Taking the pen,the boy ran.
Does the participle"taking' behaves like adjective here?

Is it true that the verb "taking" as a participle describes the object "the pen" behaving just like adjective.Am in the right point?

Comment: @yubrajsharma It does not behave like an adjective here. This is the equivalent of two sentences "The boy took the pen. Then the boy ran", but the first is subordinated to the second.

Comment: did you go through the linked grammar content http://www.englishgrammar.org/participles/

Is this writing wrong ?Why did he write like this?

Comment: Here is also another website describing participle in the same way http://www.english-for-students.com/Participle.html

Comment: @yubrajsharma Feel free to use these ways of describing how participle clauses work if they help you understand the utterances they occur in. The distinction between "modifiers" and "predications" is a fairly subtle one, and at this level it probably doesn't make much difference whether you follow the traditional analysis or the one I offer.

Comment: It was very helpfull, I accepted the answer, could you please see my this question http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107005/formation-of-passive-participle-clause It hasn't been addresed at all, is it difficult question ?